# How output a nested array in json using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

What I'm trying to do is create a stored procedure in SQL using the below table and output an expected json like in the below.

A multiple object inside an array of an object of json

```
 [
{
"Category": "Popularity",
"ItemData":[
   {
    "ItemId": "1",
    "ItemName": "CocaCola",
    "Image1": "https://www.foodbusinessnews.net/ext/resources/2019/2/CocaColaFlavors_Lead.jpg?1550182643",
    "FavId": "1",
    "ItemDesc": "gg",
    "Category": "My Favorite"
   },
   {
    "ItemId": "1",
    "ItemName": "CocaCola",
    "Image1": "https://www.foodbusinessnews.net/ext/resources/2019/2/CocaColaFlavors_Lead.jpg?1550182643",
    "FavId": "1",
    "ItemDesc": "gg",
    "Category": "My Favorite"
   },
],
"Category": "Family Style",
"ItemData":[
   {
    "ItemId": "1",
    "ItemName": "Buritos",
    "Image1": "https://www.foodbusinessnews.net/ext/resources/2019/2/CocaColaFlavors_Lead.jpg?1550182643",
    "FavId": "1",
    "ItemDesc": "gg",
    "Category": "My Favorite"
   },
   {
    "ItemId": "1",
    "ItemName": "Mountain Dew",
    "Image1": "https://www.foodbusinessnews.net/ext/resources/2019/2/CocaColaFlavors_Lead.jpg?1550182643",
    "FavId": "1",
    "ItemDesc": "gg",
    "Category": "My Favorite"
   },
],
}
]
```

**FoodAppItem** table

[image]

**FoodAppCategory** table

[image]

**FoodAppLinker** table

[image]

Since there are a lot of category in 1 item, I create a linker table to input multiple category in 1 item instead of inserting it into the main Item Table

```
FoodAppItem.ItemId = FoodAppLinker.ItemId
FoodApplinker.CategoryId = FoodAppLinker.CategoryId
```

This is my main problem => Help me guys to group the item into category and get the item in each category, I'm okay if the json output is different as long as this condition meet. Thank you

By the way I'm using api to convert the SQL output to json

This is what I have done so far

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procFoodAppSelectFoodCategory]
    @CategoryId int
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT
    DECLARE @RetCode INT
    DECLARE @RetMsg VARCHAR(100)

    SELECT @RetCode = 1, @RetMsg = ''

    SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FoodAppCategory 
                  WHERE FoodAppCategory.CategoryId = @CategoryId)

    IF @Count > 0
        SELECT  
            FoodAppItem.ItemId, FoodAppItem.ItemName, FoodAppItem.Image1, 
            FoodAppCategory.Category
        FROM 
            FoodAppItem
        INNER JOIN 
            FoodAppLinker ON FoodAppItem.ItemId = FoodAppLinker.ItemId
        INNER JOIN 
            FoodAppCategory ON FoodAppLinker.CategoryId = FoodAppCategory.CategoryId
        WHERE 
            FoodAppCategory.CategoryId = @CategoryId
    ELSE
        SET @RetCode = 3 

    SET @RetMsg = 'Empty' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    
    IF @RetCode = 3
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @RetCode RetCode, @RetMsg RetMsg

        RETURN 
    END
END
```

it display the items depends on the category id that I input, what I need is it automatically sort the item base on the category without inputting an ID

Comment: can you post your SQL query and what is your expected output?

Comment: *using the below table* Provide this table as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. *and output an expected json like* Provide JSON which matches the data provided in INSERT INTO script.

Comment: can you show me an example @Akina thank you

Comment: o_O Example of what? example of YOUR table structure/data?

Comment: a query that display this expected json @Akina

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example